# onCreate is ran twice because I set locale at app launch?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, locale, oncreate

I have been wondering for a while why my onCreate method is run twice and have now found out that it has to do with me setting the locale of the app at launch... My question is, is it necessary for it to run twice or not?

This is the code that makes onCreate run twice:

```
 /*Sets the language of the application and also returns the integer value of selected language*/
protected Integer setLanguage() {
    String lang = prefs.getString("language-key","0");
    Integer language = Integer.parseInt(lang);
    Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();

    if (!decideLang(language).equals("") && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(decideLang(language))) {
        setLocale(decideLang(language));
    }
    return language;
}

/*Sets the locale*/
private void setLocale(String lang) {
    ((Activity) context).recreate();
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
}
```

The integer that the  setLanguage method returns is later used to determine what URL to use in a later stage but I have come to realize that is not important for my question.

My question is, WHY does onCreate need to run twice because of this code?

Comment: `((Activity) context).recreate();`, as it states on the tin, recreates the Activity, so onCreate() is, of course, going to be called twice.

Comment: Of course. Wow. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Now comes the part where I figure out why exactly I even have that there... Has been a long time since I wrote this code...

Comment: I'm really not sure why you do. If it came _after_ you changed the Locale, I would say it's to reload the Activity so it knows to use the new Configuration, but since it's at the beginning, it doesn't really make sense. In any case, I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Maybe I used it to test something somehow a long time ago. Anyway. Thanks for noticing what I failed to :P Commented it out and seems to have no logical meaning to why it is there anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((Activity) context).recreate();`, as it states on the tin, recreates the Activity, so onCreate() is, of course, going to be called twice.

(From [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222411/oncreate-is-ran-twice-because-i-set-locale-at-app-launch?noredirect=1#comment91393488_52222411))